# Angular Multiple events with one function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I am using Websocket (javascript) which has the following events:

```
    ctrlScope.conn.onerror = function() {
      ctrlScope.updateStatus();
    };

    ctrlScope.conn.onclose = function() {
      ctrlScope.updateStatus();
    };

    ctrlScope.conn.onopen = function() {
      ctrlScope.updateStatus();
    };
```

As you can see I am updathing the chat status using those events, but it looks repetative, is there any way to combine all those Websocket events in one?

```
ctrlScope.conn[onError][onClose][onOpen] = function() {
   ctrlScope.updateStatus();
};
```

Additionally there is a Websocket variable: readyState which provides the status of the connection same as the events. This could replace the functions hassle, but $watch does not work on it.

Please some one help :(

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this code, but in theory you could write it like this:

```
var handlers = ["onerror","onclose","onopen"];
for(var i=0;i<handlers.length;i++){
    ctrlScope.conn.[handlers[i]] = ctrlScope.updateStatus;
};
```

This is taking advantage of the javascript ability to refer to elements using either dot notation (ctrlScope.conn.onopen) or by array notation (ctrlScope.conn["onopen"])